# Crontab will not execute my python program

Tags: python, cron

I wrote this crontab python program

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(tab="""* * * * * command""")   

job = cron.new(command=r'C:\Users\Flo\Desktop\tata\Aldo\aldoCheck.py')
job.minute.every(1)  
#job.dow.on('MON', 'THU')


cron.write()
```

But it wont work

As you see it should execute 'aldoCheck.py' every minute, but it wont do it ... I dont really know much about how CronTab works on windows (neither on ubuntu or ox, but im running it on windows) and how it works as a library in python, so every explanation it's relevant to me, thank you

P.S. Yes , i tried `command= r'python C:\...'` , but nope...

Comment: Did you try just editing the crontab in a text editor?

Comment: @SuperStew He's running on Windows, it doesn't have a standard `crontab` file. The Python module simulates it.

Comment: @Barmar ah, weird. Is there a reason OP needs to use the crontab vs the windows task scheduler?

Comment: Well i dont really want to rely on task scheduler and also i want to be able to stop or allow the program to run IN the program
Like cron.remove( job ) or cron.write(...)

Comment: Isn't this just writing a job to a cron file? This code will not actually schedule a task to run if that is what you are expecting. See the section *Running the Scheduler* in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/)